# Incorrect pixel count returned on retina display

Tags: display

I am running Emacs 26.3 on a 15" MacBook Pro with Retina display. While Emacs renders razor sharp on my screen, it does not seem to be aware of my correct pixel count. E.g.,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp

(concat
 (number-to-string (x-display-pixel-width))
 " x "
 (number-to-string(x-display-pixel-height)))

#+END_SRC
```

Returns a value of `1440 x 900`. But if I run the following,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh

system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType |grep Resolution

#+END_SRC
```

I get `2880 x 1880`.

Is this a known bug? Or is there some variable I can customize to make my system retina-aware?

Comment: Consider using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. You can check whether it's already been reported, yourself. Or submit a bug report and see if it gets closed/merged as a duplicate.

Comment: Done. Thanks @Drew!